# Scanning an Array of Objects, NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I'm working on creating a class file called "MyClass" - it works fine when I reference the class using the main class file and I can also make instances of the class with no problems by using this constructor method:

```
public MyClass(String x, int y) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}
```

I run into the NoSuchElementException error when I put it in a loop and let it read data from a text document:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileLocation));
//fileLocation is a var for the path

MyClass [] items = new MyClass[5];

for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
String x = read.next();
int y = read.nextInt();
items[counter] = new MyClass(x, y); //args require String, int
} 
}
in.close();
```

Here is the text file it is pulling from:

```
  string1    644
  string2    777
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileLocation));
//fileLocation is a var for the path

MyClass [] items = new MyClass[5];

int counter = 0;
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
String x = read.next();
int y = read.nextInt();
items[counter++] = new MyClass(x, y); //args require String, int
if (counter >= 5) break;
} 

in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove for loop.

```
int counter = 0;
while(in.hasNext() && counter<5)
{
 String x = read.next();
 int y = read.nextInt();
 items[counter] = new MyClass(x, y); //args require String, int
 counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Unfortunately, I am still getting the error. Anymore ideas?

Comment: I suspect you should use `Scanner.hasNext()`, not `hasNextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

`read` in the statment `read.next()`refers to what ?